Limit Orbits and equilibrium visualization
-I have provided some references that might help to understand what I am trying to sketch (feel free to ignore the notes which made my question appear too long.) I am trying to understand and visualize:
(i) trajectory Γ such that w(Γ) consist of 2 limit orbits and one equilibrium point. I looked at
this example which looks far more complicated in the book to think
about the sketch. There should be 2 limit cycles/nested close orbits
and a saddle at the origin (this is just a guess on my end.) But I am not entirely sure about the
sketch.


**


(ii) a trajectory  such that w(Γ) consists of two limit orbits and two equilibrium points. In order to draw this, I don't think it's enough to include this phase portrait here:


**


(iii) Lastly, in order to visualize a trajectory Γ such that w(Γ) consists of five limit orbits and three equilibrium points: is it enough to think about representing this by a spiral converging to five nested closed orbits, with three equilibrium points inside the orbits?
